# left join based on conditions in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

When i executes below query ,it throws me error saying : syntax error at or near "as".

How do we resolve this ?

Is there any other approach?

```
(select * from my_table1 where status='6') as a
left JOIN 
(select * from my_table1 where status='1') as b
ON (a.application_id = b.application_id)
```

Comment: That is not a valid query, since it doesn't start with `SELECT` (or `WITH`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below by using a selection from subquery

```
select a.* from (select * from my_table1 where status='6') as a
left JOIN 
(select * from my_table1 where status='1') as b
ON a.application_id = b.application_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the initial `select * from` clause. Moreover, there is no need for subqueries; you just need to be careful with the condition placement.

```
select *  
from my_table1 a 
left join my_table1 b on b.status='1' and
                         b.application_id = a.application_id
where a.status='6'
```

Answer (score 0):

you have select all values from you subquery the join them:

```
select a.* from (select * from my_table1 where status='6') as a
left JOIN 
select b.* from (select * from my_table1 where status='1') as b
ON (a.application_id = b.application_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from my_table1 as A 
LEFT JOIN  my_table1 as B
ON (A.application_id = A.application_id)
WHERE A.status='6' AND B.status='1'
```